# Getting partial results from windowed aggregation in Apache Flink's Table Api

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am using Flink TableApi with sql to count distinct users in each tumbling Window, But results are visible only for periods, that are earlier than Watermark.
Is it possible, to get "partial" results for periods in that still can change?

My code (run in Flink SQL)

```
CREATE TABLE KafkaTable
(
    `user_id`  BIGINT,
    `event_ts` TIMESTAMP(3),
    WATERMARK FOR `event_ts` AS `event_ts`
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'kafka',
      'topic' = 'quickstart-events',
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
      'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
      'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',

      'key.format' = 'csv',
      'key.fields' = 'user_id',

      'value.format' = 'json',
      'value.fields-include' = 'EXCEPT_KEY',
      'value.json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
      );

SELECT
        window_start,
        count(distinct  user_id),
        count(user_id)
 FROM
 TABLE(
     TUMBLE(TABLE KafkaTable, DESCRIPTOR(event_ts), INTERVAL '1' MINUTES)
     )
 GROUP BY window_start, window_end;
```

In kafka I have 8 partitions (0..7). N-th partition contains events, that are N minutes delayed from now. (Records are send every 10 seconds)

In results I see the newest window as the one that is from 8 minutes ago and contains results from all partitions.
[screenshot_from_flink_sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxnB7.png)

Instead I would like to see all windows, even if results in that windows can change - something like:

```
+I 2021-11-09 20:04:00.00         8         42
+I 2021-11-09 20:05:00.00         8         42
+I 2021-11-09 20:06:00.00         7         38
+I 2021-11-09 20:07:00.00         6         32
+I 2021-11-09 20:08:00.00         5         26
+I 2021-11-09 20:09:00.00         4         20
+I 2021-11-09 20:10:00.00         3         14
+I 2021-11-09 20:11:00.00         2         8
+I 2021-11-09 20:12:00.00         1         2
```

Is this possible using just TableApi via SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than TUMBLE, you can use [CUMULATE](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-tvf/#cumulate). This will give you a sequence of early window firings at fixed intervals.

Comment: That is interesting option, but in my case delay on some partitions is couple times greater, than the window size. So, as I understand, I could decrease the results delay only by less than a minute, because the window is firing when watermark reaches it's end (in case of tumble), or watermark reaches interval (in case of cumulate).

Comment: There are some experimental options that you might find helpful -- see https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/ab70dcfa19827febd2c3cdc5cb81e942caa5b2f0/flink-table/flink-table-planner/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/planner/plan/utils/WindowEmitStrategy.scala#L194. You could, for example, set the watermark delay to be rather short, and allow late firings.

Comment: Setting these options gives me an error:
`[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Currently, window table function based aggregate doesn't support early-fire and late-fire configuration 'table.exec.emit.early-fire.enabled' and 'table.exec.emit.late-fire.enabled'.`

Comment: That's telling you these options can't be used with windowing TVFs. You'll have to use the older window functions.